# Is there such a thing as resonance in economic underliers?

Tags: mathematical-economics, time-series

In physics the occurence of [resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance) is explained and widely understood in its linear form and subject to research in [nonlinear resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_resonance).

Example for instance are resonant frequencies of objects.

Now it is not so much of a stretch of imagination to look for resonance in economic times series.

[Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) is only a linear measure of linking time series and it doesnt explain the mechanism for resonance.

Can we explain selloffs and squeezes by resonant interactions of a complex system and is it possible to detect resonance in stock price time series of multiple stocks?